# How to include Google Analytics snippet in Javadoc?

Tags: java, html, google-analytics, javadoc

I would like to include the Google Analytics Javascript code in the head element of my generated Javadoc HTML output. How can I do this?

I figured I may need to write a custom Doclet, but this is probably going to be a nightmare of a learning curve. Isn't there a simpler way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have 2 solutions, Using maven plugin Javadoc with

```xml
<reporting>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                    <header>&lt;b&gt;test test&lt;/b&gt</header>    
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</reporting>
```

you change my "test test" with your google analytics script and don't forget to change < with < and > with >
and then you call

## mvn clean javadoc:javadoc

or using the old method http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javadoc.html#header with your html script

Comment: Well, the documentation you're linking to basically says that the text will go into the BODY of the generated HTML documents. But in order to include the Google Analytics Javascript code it needs to go into HEAD of the generated HTML documents, or am I mistaking something here?

Comment: I just realized I can have script tags everywhere, not just in the HTML/HEAD tag, so I accept this tip - thanks!

Answer (score 11):

Use CData

```xml
<configuration>
    <!-- GA Tracking code -->
    <header>
    <![CDATA[
        <script type="text/javascript">
          var _gaq = _gaq || [];
          _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-XXXXXXXX-1']);
          _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

          (function() {
            var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
            ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
            var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
          })();

        </script>
    ]]>
    </header>
</configuration>
```