# Using Gradle to generate JavaDoc with newline characters in the "header"

Tags: java, google-analytics, gradle, javadoc

**UPDATE: Made a posting on the Gradle forum.  Please star this issue so that it gets more attention  http://gsfn.us/t/4jedo**

I'm in the process of transitioning from a primarily Ant build environment into a Gradle one.  One sticking point is injecting Google Analytics and Adsense code into the JavaDoc.  This is done by putting java script code into the header or bottom panels.  For an example of what I'm currently doing, look at this question [CDATA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8520337/how-to-include-google-analytics-snippet-in-javadoc/8987947#8987947).

The problem with Gradle is that it can't handle newline characters in the string which is to be inserted.  If you filter out those characters you break the script.  Here is a code sniplet:

```
task alljavadoc(type: Javadoc) {
    source = javadocProjects.collect { project(it).sourceSets.main.allJava }
    classpath = files(javadocProjects.collect { project(it).sourceSets.main.compileClasspath })
    destinationDir = file("${buildDir}/docs/javadoc")
    configure(options) {
        header = "this is\na test which should fail"
    }
}
```

The critical part is "header =".  If you remove the '\n' character it will work just fine.  Otherwise the call to javadoc, which Gradle makes, will fail with the following error:

```
Successfully started process 'command '/opt/jdk/jdk1.7.0_21/bin/javadoc''
javadoc: error - Illegal package name: ""
javadoc: warning - No source files for package a
javadoc: warning - No source files for package test
javadoc: warning - No source files for package which
javadoc: warning - No source files for package should
javadoc: warning - No source files for package fail
```

The actual java script that I wish to include is below.  Note that I can't hack it by removing new line characters since that will break the script.

```
<script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
<!-- banner -->
<ins class="adsbygoogle"
     style="display:inline-block;width:468px;height:60px"
     data-ad-client="ca-pub-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
     data-ad-slot="xxxxxxxxx"></ins>
<script>
(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
</script>
```

As a sanity check I also passed in a string with new line characters directly to javadoc [(manual)](http://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse341/98au/java/jdk1.2beta4/docs/tooldocs/win32/javadoc.html) on the command line and it works just fine.

```
javadoc foo.java -header "This is a test
and so is this"
```

The output HTML:

```
<div class="aboutLanguage"><em>This is a test
and so is this</em></div>
</div>
```

Comment: try escaping the newlines for me: .replace("\n", "\\\n")

Comment: Did you mean "\\n" and not "\\\n"?  I tried both and both failed.  They caused the build to crash.

Comment: please expand on what you mean by 'crash'. A stacktrace would be helpful.

Comment: Spews out a javadoc application error message.  If I do "\\\n" as suggested here is the error message.

:main:visualize:classes UP-TO-DATE
:main:visualize:jar UP-TO-DATE
:alljavadoc
javadoc: error - invalid flag: -->\\
usage: javadoc [options] [packagenames] [sourcefiles] [@files]
-overview <file>          Read overview documentation from HTML file
-public                   Show only public classes and members
-protected                Show protected/public classes and members (default)

Comment: So that is a javadoc error rather than a gradle error, I would suggest experimenting with javadoc and argument files directly to figure out what is wrong, then you have a better chance of getting it to work via gradle

Comment: FWIW I suspect that gradle is handling new lines fine and for some reason javadoc has problems with the <!-- banner --> comment if it appears on a new line. Is that comment necessary? What happens if you remove it?

Comment: Yeah I already went that route.  I think gradle is trying to be smart and massages the text I send it before passing it to javadoc.  However they didn't handle newline characters correctly.  Ant and Maven have ways to handle this situation which Gradle currently lacks.

Comment: Gradle doesn't massage the text. have you tried removing the comment?

Comment: Nope not working.  I removed the comment and removed the replace() statement since we are assuming gradle is handling newlines correctly.  It now generates a lot of errors like: "javadoc: error - Illegal package name: "<ins""

Comment: Have you double-checked that your text files use `\n` as line separator?

Comment: Done something even better.  Just provided a string directly which contains \n and fails in a similar manor.  If you remove \n it works.  See the updated description above.

Comment: I could swear it was working for me yesterday, but now I see the same behaviour as you. The answer below is correct. Javadoc does not handle newlines in argfiles, you have to add '\' and annoyingly, gradle prevents you from doing that

Answer (score 1):

I have an explanation, but i don't have a solution except for creating a new feature request in Gradle JIRA.

To generate a javadoc Gradle first generates the so-called [argfile](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javadoc.html#argumentfiles) at `build\tmp\javadocTaskName\javadoc.options` that contains all individual options and than executes `javadoc @full\path\to\build\tmp\javadocTaskName\javadoc.options` command.

It is actually quite useful as you can debug the contents of that file by simply invoking `javadoc @javadoc.options` yourself from the command line.

It is possible to define multi-line values in the argfile by using the `\` character at the end of each line inside the multi-line value.

The example `header = "this is\na test which should fail"` results in

```
-header 'this is
a test which should fail'
```

but we need to get

```
-header 'this is\
a test which should fail'
```

to tell javadoc that the value continues on the next line.

Now the problem is how to output that `\` on each line.

The obvious attempt at `header = "this is\\\na test which should fail"` does not work, it will result in

```
-header 'this is\\
a test which should fail'
```

And even Groovy multi-line or slashy strings will not work and will result in similar double back slashes.

Because Gradle just replaces all single backslashes in the option values. The [JavadocOptionFileWriterContext.writeValue(String)](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/master/subprojects/plugins/src/main/groovy/org/gradle/external/javadoc/internal/JavadocOptionFileWriterContext.java#L62) method is the culprit, the `replaceAll("\\\\", "\\\\\\\\")` line in particular (a regex that matches single backslash and replaces it with double backslash ).

This escaping is required for backslashes inside a line, but it should not escape a single backslash followed by the new line character. My regex-fu is not strong enough to write such a pattern, but it is surely possible.

Or even better, the escaping mechanism inside that method should replace newline characters with a single backslash followed by the newline to hide all this stuff and allow users to declare multi-line javadoc options without the need to think or even know that feature.

I would appreciate if somebody can create an issue in Gradle tracker as i can't do so from my current location. This sentence should be replaced with the link to the issue so that people with similar problem can vote and track its progress.

Comment: Giving this answer the 50 points, even though it doesn't present a solution, since it describes the problem.  I'll create a bug report based on this answer tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to implement it in Gradle but I couldn't get it to work reliably on windows. If the options file has this:

```
-header 'this is\
a test which should fail'
```

It works nicely on linux/mac but fails on windows (tried on win7/java7 and some other windows+java6). I've tried with vanilla javadoc executable (without Gradle).

I'll get the fix into Gradle and it will work out of the box for linux/mac but not quite for windows. If you want to help out with windows support catch us at http://issues.gradle.org/browse/GRADLE-3099

Comment: Thanks for picking this up.  I got bogged down with other work when I started looking into patching it.